# Where should be .env file in Ktor project

Tags: kotlin, configuration, ktor, hocon

In Spring, for using different configs, you need to specify the active profile. And the application selects the respective file for selecting config. How to implement such a thing in Ktor? I have application.conf file, and set `connectionString: ${CONNECTION_STRING}` and in .env file I specified the value for the variable `CONNECTION_STRING`. But, application does not run saying `Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${CONNECTION_STRING}`.

`application.conf` is in `resources` folder.
`.env` is in root folder, beside `src` folder.

Comment: Ktor doesn't automatically evaluate the `.env` file, so you must do it yourself before running the application. There is a `ktor-env-config` library (https://github.com/sharpmind-de/ktor-env-config) that you can use to configure the application based on the profile/environment.